# Haskells Writer Monad its let bindings an their order

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, monads, writer

I am trying to get a better grasp of Monads in Haskell, the `Writer` and `State` Monads confuses me a bit. Here is the Writer Monad:

```
instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where  
return x = Writer (x, mempty)  
(Writer (x,v)) >>= f = let (Writer (y, v')) = f x in Writer (y, v `mappend` v')
```

How come we can use `let (Writer (y, v')) = f x in Writer (y, v mappend v')` in the `let`-binding. Wouldn't you normally have a variable-name here (e.g `let x = 4` ), whereas the `(Writer (y, v'))` returns a type based on the `newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, w) }` !?

Could it have been done without the embedding in the `Writer`-type constructor (I guess that is what it is)?

Comment: What comes after `let` is not necessarily a variable, but a *pattern*. It works exactly like a pattern in a function definition. `Writer (y, v')` is a pattern just like `Writer (x,v)` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I bit like what you would encounter in patternmatching? So you could alsoe have `let Writer (y, v) a = ...`-be another pattern?

Comment: Yes, this is pattern matching. No, `Writer (y, v) a` would not be a correct pattern. `Writer` has one field.

Comment: And this is why the State Monad has a let-binding that lookes like the following `(State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  (State g) = f a in  g newState  ` where we here see that to patterns in the `let` are used both both have the same pattern, one in which the `newtype` has been applied and one in which it occurs directly as a tupple .

Comment: I am not able to get the formatting right in these comments. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Piskator Yes, in that example the let uses two patterns: one to split the pair into its components `a` and `newState` and one to remove the newtype wrapper and define `g` accordingly.